# Angular 4 HttpInteceptor for response

Tags: angular

I have the following code to intercept all the requests and add `withCredencials:true`.

What i want is, if the response is 401, throw a message on the screen.

I have 2 problems

1. I think the code bellow is of requests. any chance to intercept response?
2. The code bellow is detouched from any componenet or dom element. even though, how can i throw message to the screen?

thanks

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpsRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(){

  }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const changedReq = req.clone({withCredentials : true});

    return next.handle(changedReq);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add appropriate function after the `handle`.

```
return next.handle(changedReq).mergeMap(res => doSomethingHere);
```

If the case is used for all calls, you can write your logic there. Otherwise
return another Observable from the `mergeMap` function or throw an exception which you can handle at the subscription and do your logic individually.

You can have an element appended to the body or in another place. Also you can have a service which gets that element from the markup. This service is used to manipulate that element - add text, show or hide or something else. In the interceptor you can inject that service and use in the appropriate way.

Comment: tnanks. what about the other question?

Comment: @Shazam Updated.